# Entity Framework Prevent Direct POCO Creation

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I am facing a scenario in which I need to prevent direct creation of entity objects.

I am using Code First. I would like to have a method somewhere only using which I should be able to create the object. Is there any commonly used practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

EF can work with entities having **private/protected** constructors.

So lets take this sample context:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    protected MyEntity() { }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Then creating an entity with `new MyEntity()` will result in compilation error.

But you can still create entites through EF with [DbSet.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.create%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) `myContext.MyEntities.Create();` and all other operations on `MyEntity` will work e.g. queries and updates etc as expected.

And of course you can also have a static factory method on `MyEntity` which manages the object creation

```
public class MyEntity
{

    //...

    public static MyEntity MyCreate()
    {
        return new MyEntity();
    }
}
```